# Having trouble equipping items on my wizard that were stashed by my monk

Tags: diablo-iii

I've been levelling my monk and found pretty nice rares for my other character. I stashed it, and once I was the right level to equip the item, I was quite pissed because it wouldn't let me equip it. Has anyone had this type of problem, and is their a way to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot would help, or describe why it "wouldn't let you equip the item"

Comment: are you trying to equip a class-specific items on a character with other class? For example: a `mighty belt` or a `mighty weapon` are only usable by Barbarians, `Quivers`, `Cloaks` and `Hand Crossbows` can only be used by DH. And so on

Comment: I can assure you, the fact that you stashed them on your Monk has nothing to do with it. Items are not bound on pickup like some are in WoW.

Answer (score 3):

The only possible answer is that you are trying to equip gear that is unusable by a wizard.

There are two types of gear, class specific, which allows only one type to equip it, and not class specific. Although the non class specific gear is not limited to only one class, not all classes can use all gear types.

The class specific gear is:

- DH : 1-Handed Bows, Quivers and Cloaks
- Wizard : Wands, Orbs and Wizard Hats
- Barbarian : Mighty Weapons and Mighty Belts
- Witch Doctor : Voodoo Masks, Sacrificial Knifes and Mojos.
- Monk : Daibo, Fist weapons and a Spirit Stones.

From the non-class specific gear all classes can use all armors and jewelry (head, torso, legs, wrists, hands, shoulders, feet, shields, rings and necklaces.)

Other than this, each class has certain weapons it can't use:

- Wizard: Polearms
- Witch doctor: Can use all weapons.
- Monk : Bows and Crossbows
- DH: Two handed melee weapons (2-handed swords maces and axes, polearms and staves)
- Barbarian: Staves, Bows and Crossbows

There are also trinkets for followers, that can only be used by a specific follower.

All this can be seen in [the official site](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/).